# How to change Moborobo's SMS time

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, settings, date-and-time

I'm currently using the Android Smartphone Management Software Moborobo and was amazed of what it can do. But I noticed that everytime I send a SMS, the time in my message is not synchronized to the one either in my PC or in my smartphone.

Please help, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time issue seems to be a known bug has already been reported and fixed in Aug 2012:

- [SMS times bug](http://www.moborobo.com/bbs/showthread.php?t=3965) - August 2012
- [Timestamp for text messages](http://www.moborobo.com/bbs/showthread.php?t=3902) - May 2012

I suggest you update to the latest version, currently at 2.1.3.767 Beta. If that still doesn't work, I suggest you [report it](http://www.moborobo.com/bbs/forumdisplay.php?f=4).